# Find nodes at k distance from given source node in an undirected cyclic graph if k<=1e9

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have encountered this problem many times. In an undirected graph, you need to get all the nodes/one node that is `k` distance away from the given source node (`src`). Given that the edge-weight is `1` for all the edges, the graph can have cycles.

**constraints:**

```
1<=N<=1e5
0 <= M <=N
1<=k<=1e9
1<=src<=N
```

where,
N = total number of nodes
M = total number of edges

Subproblem: There is only one cycle in the graph.

I tried to solve it using DFS and BFS with k breadth/depth, but that is not an efficient way to do it. How can we solve it efficiently considering the given constraints?

Comment: Did I correctly understand the question that "find a set of nodes $S$ so that for every node in $S$ there exists a path of length $k$ from a given node $v$?" Do you need to answer this question only once (or are there multiple such queries)? What is the number of edges?

Comment: Where did you encounter this task? It sounds like a problem from a programming competition

Comment: @Dmitry to me it sounds like finding all vertices $v$ such that $d(s,v)=k$. So it basically finds all vertices that have a path of length $k$ *and* there is no shorter path between them and $s$.

Comment: @Sudesh Chaudhary, How many **cycles** does that graph have?

Comment: @Dmitry yes I encountered this prob in many competitions directly or indirectly.

Comment: @VadimChernetsov There can be any number of cycles(>=0). Does having only one cycle makes it easy?

Comment: (@nirshahar *and there is no shorter path* would sure make it easier for $N < k$.)

Comment: @greybeard when $k>N$ the problem is trivial - there is no node with distance $k$ from the source node. All nodes *have* to be with a smaller distance.

Comment: (So why, given $N\le 10^5 \land k\le 10^9$, do you suggest `and there is no shorter path between them and s?)`

Answer (score 0):

Do a regular BFS (for at most $k$ iterations, if you want to optimize it), and then loop through the vertices and take all of those that have $k$ distance.

---

This approach works in $O(|V|+|E_k|)$ where $E_k$ is the set of all edges in the subgraph formed by taking all nodes with distance at most $k$ from $s$ (it is also known as the ball with radius $k$ around $s$).

Its not hard to see that this is optimal and you cant really do better than that.

Comment: if I'm doing k iteration then how is it optimized? k can have a value of 10^9. As there are cycles in the graph we can reuse any edges to achieve k distance.

Comment: Also can you please share pseudo code for your approach? For k iterations, k will also be a multiplier in the time complexity.

Comment: you always stop if there are no more vertices to search: BFS keeps track of unvisited nodes and visits them. $k$ already exists in the time complexity, in the form of $|E_k|$. Anyways, you will never do more than $O(|V|+|E|)$ operations in a single BFS run.

Comment: There are cycles in the graph. So we cannot just stop searching.

Comment: Please read the description of the BFS algorithm. It keeps track of all the visited \ unvisited nodes, so you will never get stuck in cycles.

Comment: BFS always provides the shortest path between nodes. But as we have cycles in the graph we might even get the infinite distance between two nodes. What if k = min_distance btw two nodes + p*len of the cycle  (p>0)? BFS is never gonna find it but it still exists.

Comment: A finite distance is always smaller than an infinite one, and since the nodes are connected their distance must be finite. Having a cycle or not doesn't matter for the distance calculation, since it will just add more paths with a *higher* distance, while we look at the path with the *smallest* distance

Comment: I think you did not get the question here. The complication part is with the cycles. What if k = minimum_distance btw A and B + p*(length of the cycle). Now if you just use BFS to find nodes at k distance away from A then you are not gonna find B efficiently.

Comment: You can't just do k iterations in an efficient solution because it can be as large as 10^9.

Comment: I think there is a gap between how I understand the question (as you wrote it) and what you intended the question to be. My answer relates to [the definition of distance in a graph](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_(graph_theory)), but it seems you are referring to something else.